# Manhattan plot to be saved with a transparent background

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, bioinformatics, genetics

Have a Manhattan plot, try to save it using ggsave:

```
library(qqman)
MH <- manhattan(gwasResults2, chr="CHR", bp="BP", snp="SNP", p="P", 
                     col = c("chartreuse2", "darkorange1", "gold1"),ylim=c(0,-log10(1e-06)), chrlabs = NULL,
                     suggestiveline = -log10(1e-03), genomewideline = -log10(1e-05),
                     highlight = NULL, logp = TRUE, annotatePval = NULL,
                     annotateTop = TRUE, main='DWStem') + theme_bw() + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
                                                                             plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA))
ggsave("DWSte.png",MH, bg = "transparent")
```

The file is generated but is completely blank, I mean the plot isn't coming.

Any ideas!?

Thanks:)

Comment: no love for [`ggmanhattan`](https://github.com/mkanai/ggman)?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that `manhattan` function from `qqman` package, is not compatible with `ggplot2:ggsave` since is using base graphics and not `grid` graphics. If you wish, check  the code behind `manhattan` function with `getAnywhere(manhattan)`.

Try this instead:

```
library(qqman)
library(grid)
library(gridGraphics)
library(ggplot2)

# your plot, but without the ggplot2 theme lines (they do nothing anyways)
manhattan(gwasResults, chr="CHR", bp="BP", snp="SNP", p="P", 
          col = c("chartreuse2", "darkorange1", "gold1"),
          ylim = c(0, -log10(1e-06)), chrlabs = NULL,
          suggestiveline = -log10(1e-03), genomewideline = -log10(1e-05),
          highlight = NULL, logp = TRUE, annotatePval = NULL,
          annotateTop = TRUE, main='DWStem')
# Transform the base plot to grobs, so that is compatible with grid and, therefore ggsave
p <- recordPlot()
g <- grid.grabExpr(grid.echo(p))
ggsave("DWSte.png", g, bg = "transparent")
```

Alternatively, [this tutorial](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Manhattan_plot_in_R.html) seems to give a `ggplot2` solution.